# Conjecture: the set of all permutations of primes such that the first $3$ solve $XY + Z$ forms a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers

The group law is given by function composition.

**Conjecture**:
*Let $G = \{\sigma \in S_{P}: \sigma(2) \sigma(3) + \sigma(5) \in P\}$.  Then $G$  is a subgroup of $S_P$, the symmetric group on prime numbers (their permutations).*

Firstly, is this known.  And secondly, how could I prove it?

[More info](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2213777/symmetry-group-formed-by-primes-solving-ab-c-d)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. $G$ contains $(5~7~19)$ but not its square.